# How can i keep focus on my own application or regain it when lost in delphi?

Tags: api, delphi, winapi, focus

I need to crate a software where student can do the school test given by the teacher/professor and i'm having some problem with the student part of the software.

I need to stop them change windows by alt-tab or something else but i'm not finding a way to force focus on my application or to set it back to mine when changed to another. can someone help me?

I've trying use some windows API but right now i just get my bar application light because i can't force it to the front while user is on another one. thanks.

Comment: An old link, but perhaps useful, [how to force my application to stay in focus ?](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=28938).

Comment: There is no easy, bulletproof way to do this.  What you want to do is to create a *kiosk* application.  The correct approach here is to use Windows Embedded - see :http://stackoverflow.com/a/1883057/327083

Comment: Alternatively : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3237406/327083

Comment: You have to know what you are doing here, and the system is against you. Even if you know what you are doing, it's close to unachievable, unless you make a kiosk.

Comment: Ask yourself: [What if two programs did this?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)